Retrieving Data from Analog Arduino Pin via Serial Port in MFC
I connected an ECG heart rate module to my computer and wanted to show a graph in my MFC app. I used the following code:
HANDLE m_hCom;
CString m_sComPort = L"COM4";
CString strCommand;
DCB m_dcb;
DWORD iBytesRead;
char sBuffer[128];


m_hCom = CreateFile(m_sComPort, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
SetupComm(m_hCom, 128, 128);

GetCommState(m_hCom, &m_dcb);

m_dcb.BaudRate = 9600;
m_dcb.ByteSize = 8;
m_dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
m_dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
m_dcb.fAbortOnError = TRUE;

SetCommState(m_hCom, &m_dcb);

And in my Timer Function I Read the data as following:
ReadFile(m_hCom, &sBuffer, 127, &iBytesRead, NULL);
ECG[Position] = atof(sBuffer);

With this code I get reasonable values, but when I check the values with the Serial Monitor 2 from Visual Studio (Addon), the values are different and the graph looks much more confident than with the values from my code above.

The green graph is made with the values from Serial Monitor 2, and the orange one is made with the values from my code.
This is the code from the arduino board:
void setup() 
{
Serial.begin(9600);
}
 
void loop() 
{
Serial.println(analogRead(A0));
delay(20);
}

OK, the sBuffer array shows some weird values:


What is the Arduino sending? Can we see that code, too?

Try saving or printing the strings you read from the port and see if they're reasonable.

Back when i used to send ASCII numbers across wires i would send a comma before and after every number, so if i read two commas i know what's between them has to be my number, and i then know it wasn't modified by any buffer being full or bytes being dropped, in your example a newline character \n can be used for the same purpose.

You are sending the data very quickly. So, you are probably reading multiple values per ReadFile call. Also, the Arduino is sending an int string, not float (but atof will still work).

Sorry, I set the delay in the arduino sketch to 20 ms, not 1

20ms is still pretty fast. You should check the iBytesRead variable to see how many bytes were read. It’s probably more than 3 or 4 chars. Then parse the data, splitting on newline.

You are right, there are up to 16 bytes per cycle. How do I parse the data with a new line?
